# Access the method of another class in C++

Tags: c++, class, syntax

Here's the declaration:

```
class a{
public:
    void print_fib(int x){
        printf("%d\n",b::getfib(x));
    };
};

class b{
public:
    void init();    //calculate the Fibonacci numbers, save them in `fib[]`
    int getfib(int x);
private:
    int fib[10];
};

class c{
private:
    a ca;
    b cb;
};
```

How can I access `cb.getfib()` from `ca.print_fib()`?

Comment: Choosing meaningful identifier names makes code much easier to read and understand, and therefore questions like this much easier to understand and discuss.

Comment: Cody, when printing a code example on StackOverflow it is likely that one produces a generic piece of code that duplicates the problem you are having in your real project, rather than reproduce your actual project code.

Comment: @CashCow `aa` and `bb` are still bad names.

Comment: Yes, they don't have to be the same names you use in your code. But I have a lot of trouble looking at `cb.bb()` and comparing it to `ca.aa()`, et cetera. Maybe I'm a little slow, but I think it'd be better for everyone if the names were something a little more meaningful and less cryptic.

Comment: I'd go for `foo` and `bar` for function names, `A` and `B` for types, and possibly `myA` and `myB` for instances. Identifiable yet testcase-generic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you pass `this` to ca and cb, you can use it to access cb and ca respectively.

```
class a {
    public:
        a(c *parent) : _parent(parent) {}
        aa() { parent->cb.bb(); }

    private:
        c *_parent;
};

class c {
    public:
        c() : ca(this), cb(this) {}

    ...
```

Comment: I'd be wary of using the term "parent" for this. It implies inheritance rather than composition, at least to my eyes.

Comment: Yes, I agree, I could've used a better name than parent, but I think it got the message across in this case.  Maybe owner would've been more proper.

Comment: I do not like this solution for the main reason that it unnecessarily gives a and b a depenendency on c.

Comment: What is a better alternative, if you need to work with instances?

Answer (score 1):

Re-order, else forward declare

```
class b{
public:
    bb();
};

class a{
public:
    aa(b& inst);
};

class c{
private:
    a ca;
    b cb;

public:
  void foo()
  {
    ca.aa(cb);
  }
};

// implement here
void a::aa(b& inst)
{
  // do stuff
  b.bb(); // voila
}
```

A better design decision may be to execute `b::bb()` in `c::foo()` and pass the result to `a::aa()`.. then they can be independent...

Comment: @Nim Actually class b has two methods, first it needs to be `initialized`(only once) and then has a `query()` function, what i need in `ca.aa()` is just the `query()`, any suggestion on how to implement this?

Comment: @Topro, well the pattern above should do the trick, call `b::initialize()` in the constructor of `c`, and if `b::query()` returns a value, pass this to `a::aa` (can't tell you much more unless you create a more realistic example)

Comment: @Nim i updated the code, **if no instant is created**, the `initialize()` and `query()` still works?

Answer (score 0):

if all three classes are in same file, your code should work fine.

however, if you have separate header files, include these header files into file that contains `class C`.

**Prefer Ed Heal's comment over my answer.**

Comment: You do not need to include header files - just use forward declarations. Saves on recompiliation.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue I see in the code as I see it now is the call to `b::getfib(x)` from `a::print_fib` which is not the correct way to make this call.

The function in b is not static, and cannot be unless the "cache" is also made static. Therefore to call it you need an instance of b (which you have in c). You could pass that into your function in a, but really in this case I do not see why you would need multiple instances of b.

Note also that from your code, b has not been declared yet in the header of a. Your code must be rearranged to ensure dependencies are correctly handled.

Comment: So what's your recommendation?

Comment: If you really want to do fibonnacis with lazy evaluation and cached values, you could use a singleton class for it, but beware of issues with multiple threads.